# vbscript multiple replace regex

Tags: regex, vbscript, replace

How do you match more than one pattern in vbscript?

```
Set regEx = New RegExp

regEx.Pattern = "[?&]cat=[\w-]+" & "[?&]subcat=[\w-]+" // tried this
regEx.Pattern = "([?&]cat=[\w-]+)([?&]subcat=[\w-]+)" // and this

param = regEx.Replace(param, "")
```

I want to replace any parameter called cat or subcat in a string called param with nothing.

For instance

```
string?cat=meow&subcat=purr or string?cat=meow&dog=bark&subcat=purr
```

I would want to remove cat=meow and subcat=purr from each string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, `OR` in regex is a pipe:

```
[?&]cat=[\w-]+|[?&]subcat=[\w-]+
```

In this case, this will also work: making `sub` optional:

```
[?&](sub)?cat=[\w-]+
```

Another option is to use or on the not-shared parts:

```
[?&](cat|dog|bird)=[\w-]+
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was doing the | before, but I realized the reason it wasn't working properly was because I didn't have regEx.Global = True set.

Answer (score 3):

```
regEx.Pattern = "([?&])(cat|dog)=[\w-]+"

param = regEx.Replace(param, "$1") ' The $1 brings our ? or & back
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I string two completely different patterns together? Let's say remove anything that matches "dog" or "cat"?

Comment: Thanks, although in this case, the $1 will return the ? or & of every match, so I get string&&